# Run a Macro every time sheet is changed

Tags: vba, excel

i'm still fairly new to macros, i've got a bit of code i need to run on a sheet every time it gets updated, changed, or whatever.

Here is the code I need to run: How can i do this?

```
Sub UnMergeFill()

    Dim cell As Range, joinedCells As Range

    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cell.MergeCells Then
            Set joinedCells = cell.MergeArea
            cell.MergeCells = False
            joinedCells.Value = cell.Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code module for that particular worksheet, just add this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    UnMergeFill
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The macro runs alot slower now, not sure if theres any quick fix to that. But gets the job done. Thanks

Comment: @odoc Very strange. This should have ZERO impact on execution speed. Regarding the UnMergeFill() procedure, is it critical that as the merged cells are un-merged that every individual cell that was just part of a merged one take on the value of the merged cell? That is adding a lot of overhead.

Comment: No not every cell, just every cell in columns B, C, and D need to be unmerged.

Answer (score 5):

You can boost the efficiency of your macro by locating the merged cells to process rather than looping through every cell in the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) and examining it for the [Range.MergeCells Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197310.aspx).

Within the worksheet's conventional [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx), there is an option to look for formatting. On this sub-dialog's **Alignment** tab, you'll find the option to locate **Merged cells**.

[image: Merged Cells Find]

This can be incorporated into your VBA sub procedure using the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) and the [Application object's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) [.FindFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838023.aspx).

Your sub procedure using FindFormat:

```
Sub UnMergeFill(Optional ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim fndMrg As Range, joinedCells As Range
    
    Application.FindFormat.MergeCells = True
    With ws
        On Error Resume Next
        Set fndMrg = .Cells.Find(What:=vbNullString, SearchFormat:=True)
        Do While Not fndMrg Is Nothing
            Set joinedCells = fndMrg.MergeArea
            fndMrg.MergeCells = False
            'fndMrg.UnMerge   '???
            joinedCells.Value = fndMrg.Value
            Set fndMrg = .Cells.Find(What:=vbNullString, SearchFormat:=True)
        Loop
    End With
    Application.FindFormat.MergeCells = False

End Sub
```

Slightly revised [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event macro with more environment shutdown during processing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Call UnMergeFill(Target.Parent)
    
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've opted to specify the worksheet to be processed rather than rely on the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). There is the possibility that the Worksheet_Change could be initiated by an outside process when it is NOT the active sheet.

In short, opt for bulk operations whenever possible and avoid looping whenever you can. This is not blinding fast but it should be substantially quicker than looping through the cells.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll take a look at that. Another question, is there a way to run a macro in a sheet based on if a change occurs in **another** sheet? Basically I'm trying to have a pivot table update automatically (already have the macro) once the cells in different sheet are updated by the user. I'll try making another thread if this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: wadr, that does seem to be a new question. I'll keep an eye out for it.