# excel on change not working if cell value is changed by another module

Tags: vba, excel

i have a range whose value is changed realtime but the onchange module does nothing if value is changed by other module for that range. however if i change value manually it works.
code :-

```
      Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim rng As Range
 Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range


 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J10:J43")) Is Nothing Then

  Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each cell In Target

    If cell.Value < cell.Offset(0, 4).Value Then
    cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    'Module1.OnGenOrder

         End If
        Next cell




   End If

  Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Sub
```

NOTE:- i think module   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
is not able to sense changes. The value is changed by a module in another external .xla file. but a change by simple formulas like =a1+b1 works well

update

this is code of cell to monitor

```
 =c:\Excelmacros\updateprice.xla!dataupdate($H12,"price1")
```

Comment: For starters, if you are going to change the values on that worksheet you should use Application.enableevents = false to avoid it running on top of itself. Perhaps it is and you are triggering an error control routine.

Comment: Does the other module making the change turn off event handling when it makes the change?

Comment: @jeeped i tried with Application.enableevents = false previously but still same

Comment: Regardless of fixing the problem or not you should be implementing it.

Comment: @jeeped check the updated code

Comment: @timWilliams no there isn't any such function

Comment: `Module1.OnGenOrder` should be taking a parameter for the cell in the loop or only run once when you have looped through all relevant cells in the for ... next.

Comment: @jeeped sorry that was a typo see the updated code

Comment: Both `Application.enableevents` are in the wrong place. The false should be  inside `If Not` and the true should be the last line of code before end sub. Error control should be added. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237854/run-a-macro-everytime-sheet-is-changed/32238654#32238654) for an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157296/discussion-between-avi-sangray-and-jeeped).

Comment: @jeeped i updated the code. but still not working. do you mind having a look on my pc? or any other solution?

Comment: Worksheet_Change is not triggered by calculations - you need the Calculate event.

Comment: @jeeped could please give a little idea of that

Comment: @jeeped i need help just for monitoring particular cells. else calculate event give out of stack error

Comment: @jeeped you solution is right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Event handler procedures have a simple naming convention:

```
Private Sub [EventSource]_[EventName]([args])
```

Seeing how the *event source* is `Worksheet`, it looks like your handler is in some worksheet's code-behind module; that will only ever respond to `Change` events *on **that** worksheet*.

If you want to handle `Change` events on any worksheet in `ThisWorkbook`, then handle the `SheetChange` event of the `Workbook` class, in the code-behind module for `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Notice how the changed sheet is being received as a parameter.

If you want to handle `Change` worksheet events on any worksheet *in another workbook*, then you need a class module and a `WithEvents` field - the `ThisWorkbook` code-behind can serve (a workbook *is* a class, after all), for simplicity's sake:

```
Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application
```

You'll need to `Set` that `app` event source to a valid `Excel.Application` object reference as appropriate (say, in the `Open` handler for `ThisWorkbook`), and then you can handle application-wide events:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set app = Excel.Application
End Sub

Private Sub app_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address(External:=True) & " was changed."
End Sub
```

Comment: No events will fire if EnableEvents is toggled off. Other than that, this code works for anyone that tries it.

Comment: @AviSangray protip: if you want help, "na not working" is the single most useless way to describe what the problem is. Best of luck, I'm done here.

Comment: @mats-mug what else i should have said? :-|. i myself dont know what's the issue

Comment: there wasn't anything else to say